# How to show that a disjoint sum of metric spaces is metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have encountered this question while tring to figure out why every sequential space $X$, is a quotient spaces of a metric space. If I understand correctly, given a sequential space, every sequence (including it's limit) can be identified with the space $Y=\{0\} \cup \{\frac1{n+1}|n \in N\}$. So The space $X$ can viewed as a quotient space of $\bigoplus_{(x_n) \in C} \{(x_n) \} \times Y$ where $C$ is the set of all converges sequences in $X$. My question is, How can I show that this space is metrizable?

Thank you!
Shir

Comment: On each summand, cap the metric at $1$, and define the distance of points in different summands to be $2$.

Answer (score 10):

I'll expand a little on Daniel Fischer's comment.

Let $(M_1,d_1)$ and $(M_2,d_2)$ be two metric spaces and define $d_i^*(x,x')=\dfrac{d_i(x,x')}{d_i(x,x')+1}$ for $i=1,2$. Note that $(M_i,d_i)$ is homeomorphic (although not isometric) to the metric space $(M_i,d_i^*)$. Notice that $d_i^*(x,x')\leq 1$.

We now define the metric space $(M,d)$ by $M=M_1\sqcup M_2$ and $$d(x,x')=
\left\{\begin{array}{lcl}
d_1^*(x,x')&\mbox{ if }&x,x'\in M_1\\
d_2^*(x,x')&\mbox{ if }&x,x'\in M_2\\
2&&\mbox{ otherwise }\\
\end{array}\right.$$
which one can readily check is a metric space and is homeomorphic to the $M_1\sqcup M_2$ as topologic spaces. It follows that $M$ is a metrisable space. One can then extend this definition to arbitrary disjoint unions in the usual way.

Comment: You could even set $d_i^*(x,x')=\min\{1, d_i(x,x')\}$ and still get a homeomorphic space.

Comment: @ChristophPegel That's true! I've always felt the fraction definition was easier to work with in practice though.

Comment: Note that from some point of view it would be better to allow inifinite distance and just let the distance between points from different components to be infinite. In other way, any extended metric space is topological sum of components where any two points have finite distance. If one wants to get rid of infinity, the metric can be always capped.

Comment: @user87690 That's definitely true from a category theory perspective as the injection maps of the component in to the disjoint union are metric maps, and not just continuous maps - so it defines an actual coproduct in the category of extended metric spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $(X_i,d_i),\ i\in I$, is a family of disjoint nonempty metric spaces. For each $i\in I$ choose a base point $a_i\in X_i$. We can define a metric on the set $X=\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$ by defining $d(x,y)=d_i(x,y)$ if $x,y\in X_i$ and, if $x\in X_i$ and $y\in X_j$ where $i\ne j$, then
$$d(x,y)=d(x,a_i)+1+d(a_j,y).$$